# Strong Law of Large Numbers for a i.i.d. sequence whose integral does not exist

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Prove : let $X_1 ,X_2 , ... $  be i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_1^+]=\mathbb{E}[X_1^-]=+\infty$, and $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$.
Then $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n}=+\infty}\text{ a.s., }\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n}=-\infty}\text{ a.s.}$$

I have proven that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\omega :\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\left|\frac{S_n}{n}(\omega)\right|=+\infty}\right\}\right)=1,$$

Since the events $$\left\{\omega:\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n}(\omega)=+\infty}\right\} \text{ and }
\left\{\omega:\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n}(\omega)=-\infty}\right\}$$ are asymptotic with regard to the sequence $X_1,X_2,...$ their probability is $0$ or $1$, and at least one has probability one, but I don't know how to prove both of them.

**Update:** According to the paper *The strong law of large numbers when the mean is undefined (Erickson K B, 1973)*, this proposition is wrong.

Comment: And I also wonder how can you prove that $\mathbb{P}(\{\Omega:\limsup_{n\to+\infty}|\frac{S_n}{n}(\omega)|=+\infty\})=1$. Is it proved by using Kolmogorov Zero-One law?

Answer (score 4):

Corollary 3 (p. 1195) in [Kesten (1970)][1] states:

> If $$\mathbb E[X_1^+]=\mathbb E[X_1^-]=\infty,$$ then one of the following three cases must prevail
>
> (i) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n = \infty$ w.p. 1
>
> (ii) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n = -\infty$ w.p. 1
>
> (iii) $\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n = -\infty$ and $\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n = +\infty$ w.p. 1

From the equivalence of (b) and (c) in Theorem 6:

> If $\mathbb E[X_1^+]=\infty$ then the following statements are equivalent
>
> (b) $\displaystyle\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n>-\infty\right)=1$
>
> (c) $\displaystyle\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n=+\infty\right)=1$

and the Hewitt-Savage zero-one law, if (ii) holds then $$\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n=\infty\right)=1. $$ If neither (i) nor (ii) hold, then similarly $$\mathbb P\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n=-\infty\right)=1,$$ from which the result follows.

Comment: I am still confused by the inequality $\frac{S_{m_{n_j}}}{m_{n_j}}>m$. How can it hold?

Comment: @lostlife That part of the proof does need revision. I couldn't figure out exactly how to use $\mathbb P\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{X_{n+1}>n\}\right)=1$ to show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}n=\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: By using this condition, I can only show that $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=+\infty)=1$ or $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=-\infty)=1$ or $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=+\infty)=\mathbb{P}(\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=-\infty)=1$, one of the three holds. But why not the first two, I have no idea.

Comment: @lostlife Indeed, you are correct: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-185-00/S0002-9947-1973-0336806-5/S0002-9947-1973-0336806-5.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I have read that paper.