# convergence behaviour with infinite mean

Tags: probability

let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of non-negative, i.i.d random variables with $E[X_1] = \infty$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n} = \infty$ almost surely.

There is a similar [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1831101/1127310).

---

What I thought: maybe a suitable application of 0-1 law would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $p>0$,
$$
\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}\right)\ge\liminf_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{X_1\wedge p+\cdots+X_n\wedge p}{n}\right)=\mathbb E[X_1\wedge p]\underset{p\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty.
$$

Comment: So in the last equation, you truncated the random variables so you can make use of the Strong law of large numbers?(That is $\liminf$ is just $\lim$), is that correct?

Comment: Yes the last equality is the usual Strong law of large numbers applied with the sequence $(X_n\wedge p)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, and indeed since the limit exists it is equal to the lim inf.